# Mongoengine geo spatial query with text search does not work as expected

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

The following is my query:

```
items = Item.objects(
                    location__near=[item_obj.longitude, item_obj.latitude],
                    location__max_distance=item_obj.range,
                    status__status=ITEM_STATUS_DISPLAYED
                ).filter(
                    Q(title__icontains=item_obj.search) |
                    Q(description__icontains=item_obj.search
                )
            ).hint([('location', '2dsphere')])
```

This query does not seem to work as objects outside the range is getting returned. And the item status also seems to be ignored. The range is given in meters.

The strange thing is the following query works without any issues:

```
items = Item.objects(
                    location__near=[item_obj.longitude, item_obj.latitude],
                    location__max_distance=item_obj.range,
                    status__status=ITEM_STATUS_DISPLAYED
                )
```

I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you stay away from the $near handle since mongoengine is using a deprecated call to PyMongo and your application will fail if you update mongoDB to the latest version.

What I did was to use the geo_within query, specifically the geo_within_sphere since I am finding points within a circle around locations on earth. You can find reference here: [MongoEngine geo query](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#geo-queries)

One thing that they don't explain in there is converting the radius. If you use Km then you have to do radius/6371.0 if you use miles then radius/3959.0

My queries look like this:

```
data = data_set.objects(
           location__geo_within_sphere=[[longitude, latitude], radius/6371.0]
       )
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue. Not sure why "near" would work in one case and not the other.